# Joining and counting rows from different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

So for example I need to create a report view that associates stuff to an person. Let's say properties and dogs. There is no connection between B and C

table `person`

- id
- name

table `properties`

- id
- person
- name

table `dogs`

- id
- person
- name

To tally up stuff, my report looks like:

```
select a.id, a.name, count(b.*), count(c.*) 
from person a 
  left join properties b on a.name = b.person 
  left join dogs c on a.name = c.person;
```

Intended outcome would be say for person A to own 10 properties and 20 dogs.

Somehow this join is completely multiplying the number of properties and saying the right number of dogs. How to fix the join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty method is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
select a.id, a.name, count(distinct b.id), count(distinct c.id)
from table_a a left join
     table_b
     on a.name = b.person left join
     table_c c
     on a.name = c.person
group by a.id, a.name;
```

Using a lateral join or subquery is probably faster -- particularly if there are lots of rows in the two tables:

```
select a.id, a.name,
       (select count(*)
        from b
        where a.name = b.person
       ),
       (select count(*)
        from c
        where a.name = c.person
       ),
from table_a a ;
```

By the way, if table `a` has an `id`, that should be used for linking to other tables rather than the `name`.

Comment: Using a distinct on all would make this take 20 seconds instead of just 2

Subquery proved to be much faster. Initially I thought about lateral join, but I have no knowledge on how to do those. You're right about the id, but now it's too late, other software is using the names. Thanks!